# IIS web.config Redirect // www and HTTPS in dev environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis

I have a .NET MVC 5 website where I am currently forcing https and changing www to non-www using the web config in my production environment (with a valid cert). This works fine. I also have two development environments. These environments have self-signed certs set up, and I want to force https and change www to non-www in those environments as well.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect any HTTP request to HTTPS with no www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*"></match>
      <conditions >
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)?website.com$"></add>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"></add>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://website.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true"></action>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect https www to HTTPS with no www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*"></match>
      <conditions >
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.website.com$"></add>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on"></add>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://website.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true"></action>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However, my current implementation checks "HTTPS" = off/on, which is always "off" in my development environments because they don't have valid certificates. This causes an infinite redirect loop (TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error in Chrome). I've tried all the macros I could find to check against ({URL}, {REQUEST_URL}, {HTTP_HOST}, etc...), but none of these are the fully qualified URL (ie: "http://website.dev/whatever"). If I had this, I could check if someone is ***trying*** to get to use https or http.

This isn't a big deal, but I've spent way too much time on it already, haha! Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{CACHE_URL}` variable contains full url. You can build condition with that variable instead `{HTTPS}`. It should looks something like that:

Instead:

```
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"></add>
```

use:

```
<add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^http://" />
```

And instead:

```
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on"></add>
```

use:

```
<add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^https://"  />
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect... I swear I tried that, but maybe it was a cache issue. Redirects are annoying.